# Block Users to Samba Folder

Tags: 16.04, server, windows, samba

I want to have certain users when connecting to my samba share to have access blocked to certain folders. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the samba machine go to the folder, right click the folder and select the permission tab. There you can define the permissions on 3 levels: owner, group and others. If you want to block access, you have to change the Others "Acces Files" permission to "none".

To be complete, you have to check, who is part of the indicated group above. Default the group equals your user-id, if you did not change that group yourself, you do not have to do anything else.